# Get the SUM Total of OrderAmount Where the DueDate is between 1 - 30 days past due

Tags: mysql, sql

Calculate the total Order Amount Where the Due date is between 1 - 30 days overdue. For example if Due Date is 2016-12-01 and the current date is 2016-12-15, that means the payment is 15 days overdue.
The result should look like this:

```
TotalAmount
95
```

Below is the Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders(ID int NOT NULL, OrderDate date, OrderAmount Decimal, CustomerID varchar(45), OrderName varchar(45), PaymentDueDate date);

INSERT INTO Orders(ID, OrderDate, OrderAmount, CustomerID, OrderName, PaymentDueDate) 
VALUES
  (1,"2016-10-01", 50, 123, "T-shirt", "2016-12-01"),
  (2,"2016-10-12", 45, 124, "Shorts", "2016-11-18"),
  (3,"2016-10-14", 20, 125, "Socks", "2016-10-22"),
  (4,"2016-12-11", 60, 126, "Ties", "2017-01-05"),
  (5,"2016-12-14", 15, 127, "Nike Shoes", "2016-12-30");
```

Comment: If this is your real table structure, I recommend to restructure it. Just to consider `OrderAmount` here is a varchar so any Char is possible and ruins your SUM() and therefore your TotalAmount.

Comment: amounts are normally DECIMAL. Just sayin'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer. It solved the problem.

```
SELECT SUM(OrderAmount) AS TotalAmount FROM Orders WHERE PaymentDueDate
BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement should work:

`SELECT SUM(OrderAmount) AS TotalAmount FROM Orders WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) < PaymentDueDate`

Get the current date minus 30 days (you can use NOW() or CURDATE()), if this date is before the due date, then it is in the limits.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Your answer is incorrect. The desired answer should SUM(OrderAmount) as TotalAmount and show the TotalAmount as 95 Based on the provided schema.

Comment: I was in a hurry, didn't notice at first, I edited it

Comment: @phil come on... those things can be understood, everything need not be spoon feeding.

Comment: and if the answer provided worked, it is a good practice to close the question by accepting, thanks, glad it helped you out

Comment: that is because of your table structure, the answer provided is correct. Revise your structure, don't keep `date` types in `character varying` and `integers` in `character varying`

Comment: @RaulCuth Thanks for pointing that out. The schema has been updated to reflect the actual table. i retried your query, but it doesn't work. However my answer below works

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT** *SUM*(orderAmount) AS total_amount

**FROM** orders

**WHERE** paymentDuaDate *BETWEEN* NOW()  AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement :

```
SELECT SUM(OrderAmount) AS TotalAmount FROM `orders` WHERE `OrderDate` >= CURDATE() AND `OrderDate` < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Thanks...